# More efficient way to sort an array of Vector2 ("y" decreasing)?

Tags: arrays, vector

What is the most efficient way to sort a Vector2 array based on y in a decreasing way?
example:

Given the array of vectors below:

```
Vector2(1, 4)
Vector2(5, 9)
Vector2(0, 3)
Vector2(0, 6)
Vector2(1, -2)
```

Array so ordered with "y":

```
Vector2(5, 9)
Vector2(0, 6)
Vector2(1, 4)
Vector2(0, 3)
Vector2(1, -2)
```

> **Up 1:**

The language I'm using gives me this:

**void sort_custom ( Object obj, String func )**

*Sort the array using a custom method. The arguments are an object that holds the method and the name of such method. The custom method receives two arguments (a pair of elements from the array) and must return true if the first argument is less than the second, and return false otherwise.*

I got it like this, with @Caribou answer::

```
func ord(var a1, var a2):
    if a1.y > a2.y:
        return true
    else: 
        return false

my_array.sort_custom(self, "ord")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on input set, you can't decide whether one algorithm with same time complexity will do better than another without proper bechmarking.

I would go with std::sort with custom function

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](auto a1, auto a2) {
    return a1.y < a2.y; 
});
```

The comparison function will probably be inlined, so there won't be any significant overhead on working with your structure, and time efficiency is O(n log n).

**// EDIT**
Sorry, I assumed you are using C++, but it looks like a more generic question. So the latter holds, but instead of std::sort just use one of the quick algorithms and benchmark it with other options. There shouldn't be much overhead whatsoever.

Comment: I'm not using c ++, but the language I'm using gives me this:

`
void sort_custom ( Object obj, String func )

Sort the array using a custom method. The arguments are an object that holds the method and the name of such method. The custom method receives two arguments (a pair of elements from the array) and must return true if the first argument is less than the second, and return false otherwise.
`

Comment: I got it like this:
`
func ord (var a1, var a2):
if a1.y> a2.y:
return true
else:
return false

my_array.sort_custom (self, "ord")`